# Emphasising text

Tags: css

How would you put emphasis on text? I'm talking design wise, is it easiest on the eye just to change the colour to a slightly darker shade on a word?

Example: in a chatroom there's the format `"Joe     Message"`. I'd like "Joe" to stand out more.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, if you want to maintain semantic markup, you should use the `em` tag for 'emphasis':

**[More from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em)**

> The HTML  element (or HTML Emphasis Element) marks text that has
> stress emphasis. The  element can be nested, with each level of
> nesting indicating a greater degree of emphasis.

Then its up to you- typically it depends on the kind of emphasis you wish to provide as to whether you'd use bold, italic, or different coloured or sized text...or a different font.

Answer (score 0):

You have to separate the name and the message to get what you want by css

```
<span class="">Name</span><span class="message">Message<</span>


.name{
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.message{
  display: inline-block;
}
```